# Qt: View not updating after QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows/endInsertRows

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a `QAbstractItemModel` derived model attached to a  `QTreeView`

I want to programatically append a single row to a node somewhere in my tree hierarchy.

I have a slot which is connected to a signal from my view. The signal sends the `QModelIndex` of the node to which I want to append my new row. In the slot I call `beginInsertRows(...)` using that `QModelIndex` and **the new row's row number**, append the new row to my model data, and then call `endInsertRows()`:

The value passed to `beginInsertRows(...)` is the number of child rows the parent node has **prior to appending the new node**.

That is, if there are 4 child rows, they will have row indices 0, 1, 2 and 3. Therefore the new row number added will be 4.

```
void Model::slotOnAddRow(QModelIndex parent, std::string key)
{
    assert(parent.isValid());
    Row& parent_row = *static_cast<Row*>(parent.internalPointer());

    beginInsertRows(parent, parent_row.numChildren(), parent_row.numChildren());

    parent_row.addChildRow(key);

    endInsertRows();
}
```

The problem I'm having is that after calling `endInsertRows()` my view does not update.

### Example:

Here is an example of my tree view.

[image]

### Scenario:

- I want to append a new row to **`SPREAD_1`**.
- **`SPREAD_1`** currently has 4 children rows:

  - *0*: **`inst_id`**
  - *1*: **`LEG_1`**
  - *2*: **`LEG_2`**
  - *3*: **`LEG_3`**
- The new row will therefore have row index *4*, so I call `beginInsertRows(SPREAD_1, 4, 4);`

I do just this, and **my view does not show my new row.**

### Proof the node does actually exist:

I know the row exists in my model, because if I **collapse** the `SPREAD_1` node, and then **re-expand it**, my newly added row is now visible:

[image]

### Question:

AFAIKT I've followed the [example online](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) correctly, but I'm obviously missing something.

How can I append a new row to a tree node, and have the view update?

Do I need to emit a signal or override another base class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An issue like this is indicative of an error elsewhere in the model. Without seeing the implementation of the model it is impossible to say where.

Using [Model Test](https://wiki.qt.io/Model_Test) can be very helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Literally all you need to is instantiate a `ModelTest` instance with your model

```
QTreeView(&_model);
ModelTest test(&_model);
```

If the model doesn't conform, you will get assertion failures from `ModelTest`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding `ui->treeView->reset();` after insert rows

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the index passed to `beginInsertRows` is correct. In particular the column number for the index needs to be zero if the children are attached to column zero (which they normally are)!

Answer (score -2):

Try to emit [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal with parent index as argument.

Comment: Could you try to implement [insertRows](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) method? By default it does nothing and return false.